# Download files from s3 into Hive based on last modified?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I would like to download a set of files who's `last modified` date fall within a certain time period, say `2015-5-6` to `2015-6-17`. The contents of these files will be directly put into a Hive table for further processing.

I know that [this](http://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/faqs/hive/data-directory-structure-s3-can-access.html) is possible, *but* it is either for only one file, or for an entire bucket. I would like to download all files in a bucket which have a `last modified` within a time range.

How can multiple files be downloaded into a Hive table based on the above requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the AWS SDK for Java, where a custom UDF or UDTF could be made to ping the keys and return their last modified date using:

```
S3ObjectSummary.getLastModified();
```

More info: [AWS Java SDK Docs - S3ObjectSummary](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html#S3ObjectSummary())

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myTable (key STRING, value INT) LOCATION   
's3n://mys3bucket/myDir/* ;  or  
's3n://mys3bucket/myDir/filename*'(if it starts with something common)
```

Comment: I am looking for a date range, not all of the files that have the same prefix, or are in the same bucket. I outlined this requirement in the question, "I would like to download a set of files who's last modified date fall within a certain time period, say 2015-5-6 to 2015-6-17"